# JavaSpaces - how to purge all spaces

Tags: java, javaspaces

I am not familiar with [JavaSpaces](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/javaspaces.html), but am working on an application that uses them.

**Question**

Does anyone know how to purge all spaces from the space?

The application is reading existing spaces, which I need to remove. I am guessing they are stored on the file system somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the `.jdb` file.

For me it was located here:  //rio-5.0-M3/system/external/blitz/data